# Web Scraping - Extract list of text from multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract a list of names from multiple pages of a website.
The website has over 200 pages and i want to save all the names to a text file. I have wrote some code but it's giving me index error.

CODE:

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
    URL = 'https://hamariweb.com/names/muslim/boy/page-'
    
    #for page in range(1, 203):
        
    page = 1
    req = requests.get(URL + str(page))
    soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
    row = soup.find('div', attrs={'class', 'row'})
    books = row.find_all('a')
    
    for book in books:
        data = book.find_all('b')[0].get_text()
        print(data)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Aabbaz

Aabid

Aabideen

Aabinus

Aadam

Aadeel

Aadil

Aadroop

Aafandi

Aafaq

Aaki

Aakif

Aalah

Aalam

Aalamgeer

Aalif
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mujtaba\Documents\names.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = book.find_all('b')[0].get_text()
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting the error is since it can't find a `<b>` tag.

Try this code to request each page and save the data to a file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

MAIN_URL = "https://hamariweb.com/names/muslim/boy/"
URL = "https://hamariweb.com/names/muslim/boy/page-{}"

with open("output.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:

    for page in range(203):
        if page == 0:
            req = requests.get(MAIN_URL.format(page))
        else:
            req = requests.get(URL.format(page))

        soup = bs(req.text, "html.parser")
        print(f"page # {page}, Getting: {req.url}")

        book_name = (
            tag.get_text(strip=True)
            for tag in soup.select(
                "tr.bottom-divider:nth-of-type(n+2) td:nth-of-type(1)"
            )
        )
        f.seek(0)
        f.write("\n".join(book_name) + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi Mendel, it works but it only saves 1 page to text file not all pages.

Comment: @Mujtaba Edited the answer. Just changed the write mode to `a` instead of `w`. Tested and it works for all the 200 pages

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. But i forgot there is also the main [page](https://hamariweb.com/names/muslim/boy/) which has names  i didn't mention, how to get names from this one too because it doesn't have `page` in the end.

Comment: There is a slight error when joining the last name of let's say page 1 and first name of page 2. They join each other instead of going into the new line, e.g. `name1name2` instead of `name1` `\n` `name2`.

Comment: @Mujtaba Edited answer. It can be fixed by writing `\n` to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change your parser to `html5lib` `#pip install html5lib`. I just think it's better. Second It's better **NOT** to do a `.find()` from your soup object **DIRECTLY** since it might cause some problems where the tags and classes might have duplicates. SO you might be finding data on a html tag where your data isn't even there. So it's better to check everything and inspect element the the tags you want to get and see on what `block` of code they might be in cause it is easier that way to scrape, also to avoid more errors.

What I did there is I inspected the elements first and **FIND** the **BLOCK** of code where you want to get your data and I found that it is on a `div` and its class is `mb-40 content-box` that is where all the names you are trying to get are. Luckily the class is **UNIQUE** and there are no other elements with the `same tag and class` so we can just directly `.find()` it.

[image: Sample]

Then the value of `trs` are simply the `tr` tags inside of that `block`

**(Take note also that those `<tr>` tags are inside of a `<table>` tag but the good thing is those are the only `<tr>` tags that exist so there wouldn't be much of a problem like if there would be another `<table>` tag with the same `class` value)**

which the `<tr>` tags contains the names you want to get. You may ask why is there `[1:]` it's because to start at `index 1` to **NOT** include the **Header** from the table on the website.

Then just loop through those `tr` tags and get the text. With regards to your error on why is it happening it is simply because of `index out of range` you are trying to access a `.find_all()` result list item where it is out of bounds and this might happen if cases that there are no such data that is being found and that also might happen if you **DIRECTLY** do a `.find()` function on your `soup` variable, because there would be times that there are `tags` and their respective `class` values are the same **BUT! WITH DIFFERENT CONTENT WITHIN IT**. So what happens is you're expecting to scrape that particular part of the website but what actually happening is you're scraping a different part, that's why you might not get any data and wonder why it is happening.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = 'https://hamariweb.com/names/muslim/boy/page-'

#for page in range(1, 203):
    
page = 1
req = requests.get(URL + str(page))
soup = bs(req.content, 'html5lib')
div_container = soup.find('div', class_='mb-40 content-box')

trs = div_container.find_all("tr",class_="bottom-divider")[1:]


for tr in trs:
    text = tr.find("td").find("a").text
    print(text)
```

Comment: It works, but how do i remove the empty newlines and save the output to text file

Comment: just add `.strip().replace('\n','')` on your `.text` , so it would be 

`.text = tr.find("td").find("a").text.strip().replace('\n','')`

Comment: by the way `.strip()` removes spaces at the end and beginning, the removing of new lines is the `.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having with the IndexError means that in this case the b-tag you found doesn't contains the information that you are looking for.

You can simply wrap that piece of code in a try-except clause.

```
for book in books:
    try:
        data = book.find_all('b')[0].get_text()
        print(data)
        # Add data to the all_titles list
        all_titles.append(data)
    except IndexError:
        pass  # There was no element available
```

This will catch you error and move on.  But not break the code.

Below I have also added some extra lines to save your title to a text-file.
Take a look at the inline comments.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = 'https://hamariweb.com/names/muslim/boy/page-'
# Theres is where your titles will be saved.  Changes as needed
PATH = '/tmp/title_file.txt'
    
page = 1
req = requests.get(URL + str(page))
soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
row = soup.find('div', attrs={'class', 'row'})
books = row.find_all('a')

# Here your title will be stored before writing to file
all_titles = []

for book in books:
    try:
        # Add strip() to cleanup the input
        data = book.find_all('b')[0].get_text().strip()
        print(data)
        # Add data to the all_titles list
        all_titles.append(data)
    except IndexError:
        pass  # There was no element available


# Open path to write
with open(PATH, 'w') as f:
    # Write all titles on a new line
    f.write('\n'.join(all_titles))
```

Comment: thanks, but it also prints the last 5 names which i don't want because they are not actual names.

Comment: That's probably because the section of the site your'e scraping is poorly defined.

Comment: No, the reason why it is happening is because it is trying to find all the `b` tags and you did the `.find()` function directly from the soup object. Everything that is `b` tag will be scraped. That is why I really recommend to get the block of code first.